# Call implicit before macro getting expanded

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I was wondering how can Play Json achieve the following:

```scala
case class A(s: String, b: B)
object A {
  implicit val format = Json.writes[A]
}

case class B(i: Int)
object B {
  implicit val format = Json.writes[B]
}
```

The funny about it is that the expansion of `Json.writes[A]` is using the implicit writer of `B`.

In my case, I wrote something similar to:

```scala
case class MyWriter[T](f: (T) => String)

def myMacro[T]: c.Expr[MyWriter[T]] = ... {
  q"""
    val i = implicitly[typeOf[MyWriter[$tpe]]
    ...
  """
}
```

But I obtain `couldn't find implicit value for`. I've realized that if a declare `B` and its object before declaring `A`, it works, but surely it's not why I expect.

Comment: What is `typeOf` in `implicitly[typeOf[MyWriter[$tpe]]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an expression like this:

```
def getType(typeTree: Tree): Type = c.typecheck(typeTree, c.TYPEmode).tpe

c.inferImplicitValue(getType(tq"_root_.my_package.MyWriter[$tpe]"), silent = false))
```

An example of usage for inferring of implicit JSON codecs is [here](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/blob/6f65ffdee1578873982add032455800b0491282c/jsoniter-scala-macros/src/main/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter_scala/macros/JsonCodecMaker.scala#L443).

Comment: I couldn't make this work. I wrote: `val i = c.inferImplicitValue(getType(tq"_root_.demo.MyWriter[$fieldType]"))` and then `q"""$i.toString()"""` and I obtain `value toString is not a member of <notype>`.

Comment: Nice catch! You should turn off the `silent` parameter to have a compilation error to be thrown. I will update the answer.

Comment: Great! But now I get `implicit search has failed.` Even though I write `implicit val foo: Int = 5` in `object B` and then `val i = c.inferEmplicitValue[typeOf[Int]]`.

Comment: Have you tried with `implicit val writer =  new demo.MyWriter[Int] {}` in a scope where the macro is called (not in the macro implementation)?